# Have to manually launch unity after upgrade

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, unity, upgrade

I upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 first week of May. Unity won't launch on its own. After logging in the title and sidebar are unavailable (even though I chose Ubuntu as session during login) and I have to open a terminal and launch unity for everything to show up.

I've been trying to find a better solution for the last two weeks but no success.  I've looked at Compiz settings and the Ubuntu Unity plugin is checked. I've also checked and my system supports unity (ran  /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p and it was all yes).

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with the online upgrade. I used Startup Applications to add unity which did the job. Eventually I did a clean install because I was unsure if anything else was missed.